# OpenGL: draw triangles from GPU memory

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda

I have a CUDA code that builds a mesh over some set of points. The output of the algorithms is an array of points where each 3 consequtive points form a triangle. Here is an example of the first 9 points (each component is a 4-byte float):

`XYZRGB XYZRGB XYZRGB XYZRGB XYZRGB XYZRGB XYZRGB XYZRGB XYZRGB ... 
 <---1st triangle---> <---2nd triangle---> <---3rd triangle---> ...`

Now I want to draw these triangles using OpenGL. My current approach is the following: I download the output list of points to CPU memory, pass it to OpenGL and draw them. The obvious problem here is copying data from GPU to the main memory and back to GPU. Copying data in one direction takes up to 10ms. So I want to optimize my code and eliminate memory transfers. Is there a way to tell OpenGL to use my GPU memory?

The main cycle in my code looks like this:

```
std::vector<Point6f> mesh(config.MaxMeshIndex);
for (;;)
{
    //build mesh
    builder->Build(devPoints.ptr(), devPoints.size());
    //download to the main memory
    auto meshSize = builder->GetMesh(mesh);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    // tell OpenGL to use points from the main memory
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, meshSize * sizeof(Point6f), mesh.data());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, meshSize);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

I know OpenGL abstracts much, so maybe there is no API call for this. How about extensions? Or maybe abandon OpenGL in favor of another library?

It's a custom code, so I don't need to be it compatible with all the existing video cards. I need it working on NVidia cards, 1080 GTX specifically.

Comment: this is called CUDA/OpenGL interop, and there is CUDA API support for it as well as CUDA sample codes demonstrating various approaches.  You might want to review those.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks for your comment. I didn't know about this feature and I googled into a wrong direction.